# Is Default serialization format of Date has changed with recent Spring boot versions/Jackson Versions?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I am in the process of updating the SpringBoot version to 2.3.1.RELEASE from 2.2.2.RELEASE. Suddenly all date format of all my API responses has changed(In the timezone representation section).

From `+0000` to `+00:00`

```
"timestamp": "2020-05-19T05:46:49.469+0000" -  2.2.2.RELEASE

"timestamp": "2020-06-30T09:55:23.014+00:00" - 2.3.1.RELEASE
```

This is my Simple POJO: I have not added any `@JsonFortmat` configuration for the date field.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class BuildInfo{
    private String message;
    private Date timestamp;
}
```

and my controller method

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/buildinfo", produces = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<BuildInfo> getBuildInfo();
```

I have not added any serialization/ deserialization logic and I have developed only with SpringBoot's default behavior. I am trying to search any release document regarding this change, but could not find any.

Below changes, I can perform to adapt these changes

1. Using `@JsonFormat` annotation with customized pattern in every date field(but I cannot do it as this is client library)

   ```
      @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
      private Date timestamp;
   ```
2. Injecting `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` in application level.

```
 @Bean
 public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
     return builder -> builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
 }
```

But I would like to narrow down the root cause for the format change? starting from which version of Jackson/Spring libraries?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.11 change and dependency is updated in this version https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.3.0.RC1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from [jackson-databind 2.11.0](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2643).([diff](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/commit/4b51149917b49b7ffef1c15467f1e90657d4c3ed))

- [Spring Boot 2.2.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dependency-versions-coordinates): 2.10.0
- [Spring Boot 2.2.8](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dependency-versions-coordinates): 2.10.4
- [Spring Boot 2.3.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dependency-versions-coordinates): 2.11.0

so, it seems this behavior is Spring Boot 2.3.0 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Change is documented in Spring Boot 2.3.0 RN's, in the [section stating the changes in Jackson version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#jackson), where it explicitly mentions "a change to the default formatting of java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following Spring Boot property to format your JSON dates: spring.jackson.date-format. Note this only works on java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar objects.